# How to remove multiple input items from a list

Tags: python, list, input

I have a question where I have to take multiple inputs and remove them from a set list in the beginning.

If my list is
list[apple, banana, cherry]

and the code for the input is
input()
and the user enters "apple, banana"

how do I remove those two items from the list and then print the list? The user has to enter everything into 1 input box

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Quite simply, you solve the problem by repeating your tutorial or chapter on the `list` data structure.  The available removal methods are in that material.  Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

```
lst = ['apple','banana','cherry']

strings = input().split(',')

for x in strings:
    lst.remove(x)
    
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
>>> apple,banana
['cherry']
```